# Dynamically generate Checkbox group and save value into table and show checked status based on saved value in that table in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular9

I have two tables, **Role** and **UserRole**. In Role table there are some value like “Admin”, “Staff”, “Employee”. Now I need to create a HTML form where a group of Checkbox will be generated based on Role table value. There would be a Save button in the form. If I click the save button checkbox value would be saved into the **UserRole** table. After save, the form will be refreshed and the Checkbox group will be checked or unchecked based on saved value in **UserRole table.**

Can anyone give me an example how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please, provide the code that causes you trouble. This page's purpose is not to set up an entire page for you.